# onCreate() callback of DialogFragment not called (where to initialise Views?)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I want to show custom dialog using `DialogFragment`. However I fail to initialise layout Views before I need to modify them.

This is my `DialogFragment` class.

```
public class RemoteProgressDialog extends DialogFragment {

private TextView lockProgress;
private TextView foldProgress;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_NoActionBar);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remote_progress_dialog, null);
    lockProgress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lock_progress);
    return view;
}

public void lockFinished() {
    lockProgress.setCompoundDrawables(
                                    null,
                                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icn_mycar_sunroof_open),
                                    null, null);
    // TODO: remove
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    showLockProgress(false);
    dismissDialogIfNeeded();
}

public void showLockProgress(boolean show) {
    lockProgress.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}

private void dismissDialogIfNeeded() {
    if (lockProgress.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        // TODO: add conditions
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

I show the dialog in a `Fragment` like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    progressDialog = new RemoteProgressDialog();
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    progressDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), REMOTE_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
    progressDialog.showLockProgress(true);
    return true;
}
```

At first I tried to build the Dialog using `AlertDialog.Builder` but I was getting `NullPointerException` because `onCreateDialog()` method was not performed before `showLockProgress()` so `lockProgress` was null. Well, I didn't need `AlertDialog` anyway so I end up using this approach hoping it would help to solve the problem.

Unfortunately it didn't help. `lockProgress` is still null when the method `showLockProgress()` is called. I put a breakpoint in `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` methods of the `DialogFragment` as well as in `onAttach()` of hosting `Fragment`. The one in `onAttach()` gets triggered so the instance of `DialogFragment` should be created but neither `onCreate()` nor `onCreateView()` seem to be called. When I long-press the button, `showLockProgress()` is called but `lockProgress` is still null.

Why aren't my views initialised when the instance of dialog is created or immediately after I call `DialogFragment.show()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem I guess is that your `public` method is called before `onCreate` and etc. because after calling `show` to your `DialogFragment` it takes time to initialise the dialog, it's view and all variables. So the way you can handle this the right way in my opinion is just create a `boolean` variable which you set before showing your `DialogFragment`. Something like this :

```
public class RemoteProgressDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private boolean mShowText = false; // default value

    private TextView lockProgress;

    public void setShowText(boolean showText){
        this.mShowText = showText;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.remote_progress_dialog, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // initialise your views here
        lockProgress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lock_progress);
        showLockProgress(mShowText);
    }

    public void showLockProgress(boolean show) {
        lockProgress.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }

}
```

and you can do something like this before showing your `Dialog` :

```
progressDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), REMOTE_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
progressDialog.setShowText(true);
```

So this way you won't get `NullPointerException` and you can be sure that depending on the `boolean` which you set, your `TextView` in `RemoteProgressDialog` will be hidden or visible  when it is initialised.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

I think the problem is that you try to `showLockProgress` before the dialogFragment is created and displayed which leads to an attempt to access `lockProgress` before it's assigned.

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    progressDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), REMOTE_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
    progressDialog.showLockProgress(true);
    return true;
}
```

Here is what happens when you execute that code:

- The DialogFragment's [`show`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show%28android.app.FragmentManager,%20java.lang.String%29) method "*is a convenience for explicitly creating a transaction, adding the fragment to it with the given tag, and committing it*" - it creates a transaction to add a fragment and commit it.
- But the FragmentTransaction's [`commit`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29) method actually schedules the commit of the transaction at some point in the future, when the main thread is ready.
- The `onLongClick` method is executed on the main thread so the actuall commit of the transaction (along with the fragment creation) is scheduled to happen at some point after this method finishes. But inside it you try to access the stil-not-initialized member `lockProgress` (inside `showLockProgress`).

**Solution:**

Use the Android-Developer's [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21850259/306739) and implement a boolean member that can be used to show (or not) the progress after the view was created (in `onViewCreated` for example). This way you only tell the DialogFragment from outside that it should display the progress (or not) but let it deal internally with the "when" and "how".